# Instantiating objects dynamically at runtime C# or Python

Tags: c#, python, class

I want to simulate a virus spread throughout a population. I have a Human class with specific properties and I want to also simulate reproduction and make another Human object when the reproductionTimer runs out in each Human object and delete the object if it reaches a randomly generated age from 20-100 or if it dies from the virus.

How would I do this since it requires making objects at runtime? Specifically I would like to know how to reference each object, because I need to simulate interaction too.

Comment: "_Instantiating objects dynamically at runtime_" - Yeah that'd just be `Human human = new Human();`. Clearly you need some sort of collection to manage all your instances.

Comment: But wouldn't 'human' be overwritten again and again because I use the same object name? Or will it not overwrite and I just need to assign a name property to each one and manage it somehow? And if it is like that, how would I manage all the objects and count the number of objects

Comment: Are you familiar with **collections** (arrays and lists and all that jazz)? You might want to [look into them](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybcx56wz.aspx).

Comment: I know lists and arrays, so would I just use a foreach to iterate through all the objects? and referring to my previous question, if I use use Human human = new Human(); since there is another object called human, will human be overwritten or will another copy of it be made, and how will I reference the object if both objects have the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create the objects and put them into a container of some sort (a `List<Human>` or maybe a `Queue<Human>`.

Then check every time step to see if your humans have reached a certain age and kill them.